# Boostrap modal only showing first record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that appears when a user clicks a delete link on my index page but this is only showing the first record regardless of what row is clicked, i think i'm missing something in the "@data_target" part of my code but unsure.

Code is as follows:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "ModelName", new { id = item.ID }))
    {
        var myModal = "myModal" + item.ID;

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Account_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Index", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "DeleteRecord", @data_target = "myModal" })

                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <center>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Record</h4>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <center>
                                   Record ID :<span><b>@item.ID</b></span><br />
                                    Account Name : <span><b>@item.Account_Name</b></span><br />

                                </center>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <center>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
                                </center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

and then the function is

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('.DeleteRecord').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //perform the url load  then
        $('#myModal').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
        return false;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you function as below. `$(this).closest('td')` will select parent `td` element of clicked `.DeleteRecord` button. Then it will find `#myModal` inside that `td`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.DeleteRecord').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //perform the url load  then
        $(this).closest('td').find('#myModal').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
        return false;
    });
});
```

In your code `$('#myModal').modal(...);`, this has used `id` selector which will always give you first element which has `myModel` id.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, This community is so great and is really helping me develop my knowledge and understanding

Answer (score 0):

It should be data_targer="#myModal"

Comment: Thanks for commenting, i have tried that and its made no difference :(

Comment: Try to remove the tab-index =-1 i think its preventing to access the jquery

Comment: Thanks again Alex, still no joy :(

Comment: May i ask again what is your problem and what output you want?

Comment: The modal that appears on the index page only ever refers to the first record., i have a delete link which makes the modal appear and no matter which record i select it only shows data and deletes the first record rather than the one i'm selecting

Comment: I see, try to check your Jquery for the process/controller phase to which item will be deleted.